# How to check the new record is inserted or not to db in java

Tags: java, mysql, timer, listener

I need to check whether a new record has been inserted into the database or not. I am creating Listener to poll the database continually with some delay I need to check new record is inserted or in to the table in the new record comes I want to get that data otherwise no need to get data from table.
This is my Listener classs..

```
public class GetGpsDataListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 1000, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

This is my Timer class..

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Inside run");
        // Here I will connect to database to check new record from table..
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need to know if new records have been inserted, and what those new records are? And are you only interested in inserts to one table, or to a number of different tables? And what is inserting in to the table; your application, or a different application?

Comment: In only one table and one appliction..

Comment: you can preserve primary key value and check it

Comment: your update query line returns true false , dependingg whether the updation was succesful or not

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is doing all the inserts then I don't think I'd poll the database to see if a new record has been inserted. Polling the database is likely to be resource intensive, especially if the table gets large, and also generally means you need to retain some state within your application to allow you to see what has changed.

When your application does an insert, it will be able to see

- whether the insert was successful
- what the id of the inserted record is

I'd just allow the code that does the insert to communicate to a separate class that the insert was successful and what the id of the inserted record is. The separate class can than do whatever it needs to do.

If this needs to be done asynchronously you could consider pulling the ids on to a queue and allowing your timer task to read them.